# Save for web from selected artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, artboard

I have several pictures in different artboards. I would like to save "for web" picture in artboard #2 . When I do "save for web" I'm always pointed to dartboard #1 an I must use mouse o move right picture. This is not convenient. How to fix it?

Another problem I would like to solve - I need to have size in "save for web" menu exact of picture I would like to save and not some magic frame AI is offering me. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

As for the first question, the only option you have is to always click on the Artboard you want(#2) to save then go to the settings then **Save for Web**. There is no shortcut to that.

Aas for your last question, Illustrator gives you an option of whether you want the **Save for Web** to retain its original image proportions or you use your own sizes as indicated on the red box which you may decide to check or not on the picture below. The setting is on the right hand side of the window panel.

[image]